# Error When Comparing Two Dataframes, Column Names are Same

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and I'm attempting to compare the two dataframes, so if the value of df1 is in df, drop the row. I've listed out both columns, and they're named exactly alike.

```
df   Permit Number  Sub Permit   
     BLD-00045         NaN          
     ELE-2019        BLD-00045     
     PLM-2018        BLD-00045
```

```
df1  Permit Number    Sub Permit    
     BLD-00001         NaN          
     ELE-2019         BLD-00045     
     PLM-7777         BLD-00045
```

In my code below, I rename the column in another dataframe (df3) so that I can merge them into a new dataframe (df1). I attempt to set the index to the permit values, but don't wish to drop the index (because I want to keep the permit numbers), then compare them.

My goal would be to keep the rows BLD-00045 and PLM-2018, but drop ELE-2019 because it's equal between the two dataframes.

```
df3.rename(columns={'permit_num': "Permit Number"}, inplace=True)
df1 = pd.merge(df, df3, on='Permit Number')
df.set_index('Permit Number', inplace=False)
df1.set_index('Permit Number', inplace=False)
df = df.loc[df['Permit Number'] != df1['Permit Number']]
print(df)
```

I keep getting ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series object.

Comment: Try `isin` df.loc[df[col].isin(df1[col])]

Comment: This is what worked for me, but I can't mark it as the answer

Comment: added as an answer for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `isin` with `~` to reverse the logic,

for example :

```
print(df.loc[df['Permit Number'].isin(df1['Permit Number'])])
      Permit Number Sub Permit
1      ELE-2019  BLD-00045
```

If I understand your logic correctly you want to drop the above row ^

```
print(df.loc[~df['Permit Number'].isin(df1['Permit Number'])])
```

you can do this by adding `~` which reverses the logic or acts as a `not isin`.

```
      Permit Number Sub Permit
0     BLD-00045        NaN
2      PLM-2018  BLD-00045
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = df.merge(df1, how='outer', indicator=True)
df3 = df2[df2['_merge']=='left_only'].drop(labels='_merge', axis=1)
```

IIUC, you need only the rows present in df but not in df1.